# Do something with last value in loop in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

Lets say I have a loop and an if statement in the loop. If i is true in the loop it prints with a space or comma and it does this for the rest of the i's that are true, but I want to do something else with the last i that that is true. How would I do this?

```
for (i = 0; i <= somenum; i++){
    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        cout << i;
    }
}
```

I want to figure out the last value that follows the condition and do something else with it.

Comment: Post your code or we're just guessing.

Comment: Show us example code that is close to what you want to do with the question targeted to that example.  It's not at all clear from the question as it currently stands.

Answer (score 1):

There are really three ways to approach this problem. To illustrate this I'm going to use the example that you want to have a for loop print the numbers 0-9 separated by comas and spaces.

(1) Make the loop do the same thing every time, but modify your result after the loop. An example of how to do this is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int, char**) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    ss << i << ", ";
  }
  ss.seekp(-2, std::ios_base::end);
  ss << '\0';
  std::cout << ss.str();
}
```

(2) Exit your loop before your last iteration and handle the last case outside the loop:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << 9;
}
```

(3) Special case your last iteration in the loop. This option is bad, and you probably only want to do this in cases where you can't make 1 or 2 apply. The reason this is bad is because your conditional in the loop will be executed every time, and it will only be true once.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if (i == 9) {
      std::cout << i;
      break;
    }
    std::cout << i << ", ";
  }
}
```

In most cases option 2 is your best bet from a performance standpoint, but sometimes option 1 provides cleaner code which can be valuable.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a "sequence" then you have no way of knowing if an element is the last or not. If you're using a `for` loop with a known length then it's trivial:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {

    if( i == length - 1 ) {
        // do something for the last element
    }
}
```

Reading your question, it sounds like you want to print a comma between elements but obviously don't want a trailing comma. The solution is not to test on the last, but to actually test on the **first**, like so:

```
bool isFirst = true;
iterator it;
for( it = sequence.begin(); it != sequence.end(); it++ ) {

    if( !isFirst ) print(", ");
    isFirst = false;
    print( element );
}
```

Comment: yes this is what I am trying to do. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user4130716 What are you trying to do?